# ms access query to search a text or characters or a string and update/add a value to the other field

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I would like to search a word or a certain characters from  Field1 (say Camel or Cam) and Field2 like Animal and if found from either on both Fields or on Field1 automatically it will update the Field3 with a value "ZOO".
I have multiple search using like or contains, because fields contains a different words.
I am newbie to sql and don't know really how to start with this.
Thank you and for the help.

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
"UPDATE table SET field3 = 'Zoo' Where field1 = 'Cam??' OR field2 = 'Animal'"
```

where, ? is a wildcard in *Access*.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this one.. can I use the wildcard as the first character like '??Cam' , say I have a other words before "Cam". Cheers

Comment: Is it possible to update the Field3 with two different value to Zoo or Park? Say Field1 = 'Cam' then Field3=Zoo or if Field1 is blank then Field3 is Park.. Thank you